# Connect Netbeans 8 to SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, netbeans, connection

Win 8.1
Netbeans 8.0.2
SQL Server 2014

I'm trying to create a (very) small project -- Nothing huge, just get data from SQL Server to Netbeans.

Problem is I can't seem to get a connection. Nor can I find any information about how to connect these versions. I've tried following steps to connect older Netbeans to older SQL versions, but nothing works. I just get errors compiled by more errors. Google has not been my friend here :-(

Anyone out there know a step-by-step resource that can connect Netbeans 8 to SQL 2014?

Or am I trying to do something regarded as impossible?

Thanks,
Jason

FYI -- SQL is setup for Windows Authentication.

Comment: Probably this one still applies: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNqLia7rIPM

Comment: Nope, I did everything in that video 20 different ways. Keep getting "Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433 using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"